# bootstrap transition to last slider on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I want to show the last slider as 1st item in bootstrap carousal.I have x number of slides(dynamic slide).I want to load last slide on load.now It shows 1st item on load.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width:450px">
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active"><img src="img/IMG_2.jpg"></div>                
            <div class="item"><img src="img/IMG_3.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="img/IMG_1.jpg"></div>
            <!-- Carousel nav -->
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <script>
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 4000,
        scroll:last //need to change here
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: If you want to show the last slide on load, why can't you give it as the first item? I understand, it's dynamic as you've mentioned in the question. If it's dynamic, just reverse it's order.

Answer (score 2):

Add `active` class to the last item like,

```js
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000,
});
$('#myCarousel').find('.item:last').addClass('active')
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width:450px">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item"><img alt="img/IMG_2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img alt="img/IMG_3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img alt="img/IMG_1.jpg"></div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to add 'active in jquery'